# How to access vuetify-component with codeceptjs

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, vuetify.js, codeceptjs

I'd like to write some tests witch codecept.js but I'm not able to access the vuetify components.

```
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs7>
        <v-text-field
          ref="video1min"
          v-model="video1min"
          :rules="[rules.required, rules.youtubeVideo]"
          clearable
          class="pt-0"
          placeholder="Youtube Link"
        />
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs5>
        <v-checkbox
          v-model="defaultVideo"
          v-ruid="'defaultVideo'"
          label="Default Video"
          color="primary"
          class="default-video"
          @change="setDefaultVideo"
        />
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
```

I added an `v-ruid` which normally can be clicked like that:

`I.click('[data-ruid=defaultVideo]');`

But witch the vuetify components, I always got that error message: `element not interactable`

It's because the `data-ruid` is added to div around the checkbox. How can I access the checkbox directly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selector to get `input` dom element inside.

This selector should work:

```
'[data-ruid=defaultVideo] input'
```

Edit:

Also in case of `v-checkbox` you also can click on label.

Selector is:

```
'[data-ruid=defaultVideo] label'
```

Comment: that does not work, then I got `element not interactable` as error

Comment: Maybe your element is not visible at the moment. Can you also try `I.click({css: '[data-ruid=defaultVideo] label'})`

Comment: Also wrong, got that error message: `Clickable element {"css":"[data-ruid=defaultVideo] label"} was not found by text|CSS|XPath`

Comment: I've added an image witch the css from inspect mode

Comment: Strange. Can you provide more source code and information about versions of vuetify, vue?

Comment: So I posted the whole `v-layout` where the checkbox is located. I use `"vuetify":"~1.0.18"`and `"vue": "^2.6.10",`